# Android glsl discard problem

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es

Whenever I use `discard` or an `if` statement in my shaders, I get an error message with the text

```
<qgl2DrvAPI_glAttachShader:398>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

I think this is a version problem, but I'm really not sure.